# Which photographers do you follow on twitter?

Tags: blog

Similar to the question about who's blogs to follow ... 
Who represents photography well in the twitterverse?

(BTW, I tweet about too many things besides photography, so I am not a good candidate. @theChrisMarsh)

Comment: As an aside, @photogangle tweets all the new questions posted here...

Comment: Should your twitter name be moved to your profile? At least one person flagged this question as spam.

Answer (score 4):

David Hobby, aka [@strobist](http://twitter.com/strobist)

Answer (score 4):

Top 3: @Heninger, @TreyRatcliff, @Llywellyn

Some others: @strobist, @_davidjay, @vincentlaforet, @jasminestar, @gluwater, @muenchworkshops

Comment: Amazingly similar to mine.

Answer (score 3):

I follow, indirectly, [DIY Photography](http://www.diyphotography.net/) because I'm into that sort of thing and you can learn a lot, not to mention save some serious coin. Besides, I got [featured](http://www.diyphotography.net/create-a-complete-strobing-system-from-foamies-velcro) there not long ago, so it makes me loyal. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I follow DPS (not photographer tho)

But love the question.

Answer (score 2):

ScottBourne has some great contests as well as useful info.  He is the host of th PhotoFocus podcast.

Comment: Just a warning, don't ever disagree with him on Twitter over anything.  I know several photographers (including myself) who have been blocked by him for questioning something he said.

Answer (score 0):

I follow [@KaiManWong](http://www.twitter.com/kaimanwong). He's a photographer that works for DigitalRev. I find his [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/user/digitalrevcom) reviews and videos pretty funny. "Asian guy with a funny British accent" he calls himself.

Answer (score 0):

[@kevinwinzler](http://twitter.com/kevinwinzeler), [@shatterkiss](http://twitter.com/shatterkiss), [@DonMacAskill](http://twitter.com/DonMacAskill), and [@SmugMug](http://twitter.com/SmugMug)

Comment: Don (my boss) is more of a web tech / valley startup tweeter than a photography tweeter. There's a number of photographers at the company, but Don's one of the last folks in the company that comes to mind as a serious photographer.

Comment: Don's tweets are great but they are not photography heavy. @Baldy has more photo content but not exclusive photography.

Answer (score 0):

I like following [@DamienFranco](http://twitter.com/damienfranco), [@ScottBourne](http://twitter.com/ScottBourne), [@pixelatedimage](http://twitter.com/pixelatedimage), [@TamaraLackey](http://twitter.com/TamaraLackey), [@nicolesy](http://twitter.com/nicolesy) and [@mostlylisa](http://twitter.com/mostlylisa)

Answer (score 0):

This is great to find inspiration :

@dailyshoot : Daily shooting assignments to inspire and motivate you to practice your photography, and share your results!

Answer (score 0):

Agree with poster who mentioned [@KaiManWong](https://twitter.com/kaimanwong).

Additionally [@CanonRumorsGuy](https://twitter.com/canonrumorsguy), [@NikonRumors](https://twitter.com/nikonrumors), [@Lightroom](https://twitter.com/Lightroom), [@AP_Magazine](https://twitter.com/AP_Magazine), and [@1854](https://twitter.com/1854) (British Journal of Photography), [@CarlZeissLenses](https://twitter.com/CarlZeissLenses).