# What good landscape photographers shoot primarily in the Northeastern United States?

Tags: landscape, photographer

I am an amateur landscape photographer living in New York.

I have been looking for some good landscape photographers who primarily shoot in the Northeast. I would like to follow their work, get inspired from it, and use their photographs to scout new locations which I could shoot.

I do a lot of flickr and 500px, but I mostly stumble upon works of photographers working out west in California or the Pacific Northwest.

Could you guys point me to some photographers who primarily shoot in the Northeast?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/which-photographers-do-you-follow-on-twitter

Comment: You need to get yourself up to the Adirondacks if you can.  Some truly stunning landscapes up there :-)  Here is one of mine - http://www.flickr.com/photos/miketendler/7520545538/in/set-72157630422667568

Answer (score 1):

Aside from specific photographers, you might want to search for Flickr groups that are relevant. For example [Top 20 Vermont Pics](http://www.flickr.com/groups/vttop20/) was among the top hits for [vermont landscape](http://www.flickr.com/search/groups/?w=all&q=vermont+landscape). Or use the [Flickr Map](http://www.flickr.com/map?&fLat=42.642&fLon=-73.1909&zl=11). Sort by "Interesting", zoom to the area you're interested in, and refresh (little button with two green arrows).

Either way, when you see something you like, you can look more closely at that photographer's work to see if he or she does a lot of good landscape work in the region, and you can follow the ones who do.

Comment: I can only suggest doing the same... :)

Answer (score 0):

While he might be a bit "norther", and perhaps even a bit "easter" than you're looking for, you might want to take a boo at [Freeman Patterson](http://www.freemanpatterson.com/)'s work. He's based in New Brunswick, which isn't too terribly different in terms of climate and terrain from the Maine/New Hampshire/Vermont/Massachusetts area, and much of his work has been done in those areas as well. There's about fifty years of photographic material to go through right there, and he's done a lot of writing as well.